# Start small and grow larger with SQL Server 2012 - code and price wise

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, scalability, cluster-computing

I am developing my new web / mobile app using ASP.NET 4.5 and SQL Server 2012. I expect my DB to be very large, and reach terabytes of data. I know that in order to pick up with the high write and read of my application, as well as the data capacity, I will need to use clustering. What I wanted to know if there is a solution that will enable me to start with one server / one database and when I need more capacity room, I can implement it without making changed to my code.

I prefer working with SQL Server 2012 and not using NoSQL solutions. What are my options. Are there any DBaaS solution that allows you to query against one database, but behind the scenes implement a clustered environment that can scale to terabytes of data storage.

Choosing Amazon RDS for SQL Server 2012 is a good way to start, but what happens when I need more room, larger than 1TB. Furthermore, it's not recommended to use large databases. SQL Azure and federation is one option, but it seems to expensive for storing large databases and you need to make changes to your code. Maybe there is some kind of middleware that can take care of that?

What I need:

1. SQL Server 2012 deployment, start small and be able to grow when database capacity grows
2. Being able to easily backup and restore data
3. Start with a regular SQL Server 2012 installation and go to a more advanced architecture without code changes to my application
4. Considering a DBaaS solution
5. Need the solution to support triggers

Just wanted to add that the problem with SQL Azure and Federaion is that I can't backup / restore the database in terms of data curruption. Which for me is a really deal breaker. I want a solution that will allow me to easily backup and restore the data.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Azure is way to expensive for high read/write web apps for my needs.

Comment: There is no mention of cost as a factor besides the title in your question, nor specifics on IO requirements.

Comment: ok, let's put the costs aside. My main problem with SQL Azure and federation is that I can't backup and restore data.

Comment: What data volume do you expect to start with and how quickly will it grow, i.e. how fast will you get to 1TB? And are you predicting "terabytes of data" based on something you already know with certainty (e.g. because it's an in-house application), or on projections from a business plan?

Comment: reach 1 TB of data in 3 monthes

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "easily backup and restore?"  If you are dealing terabytes of information, easy just isn't going to happen.  Just the file copies alone will take hours, and require a very large amount of space for you to keep backups.  And if you are really keeping terabytes of information, I don't think that you'll be happy with the downtime associated with that kind of process.

In my experience (not exhaustive by any means) there just isn't any good way of automatic scaling using SQL Server.  In all honesty, I'm not sure it's easy or automatic in any sort of DB scheme, but for sure nothing all that simple for SQL Server.

Apps that I've done with some of the same requirements you have, and I have done a few, I've just "sharded" teh database and used code to aggregate data that needs to cross servers.

Can you refine your requirements a bit?

Comment: I try to keep things simple. I want to start with one server and pay less to start, and pay more when data capacity grows. I prefer having servers with smaller DB so backup and restore will be fast if data curuption occurs.